# Can I use baking powder to replace cream of tartar

Tags: pie, apples

I need cream of tartar to make a special apple pie,but I have none can you tell me the correct substitute
I need a proper answer
The pie is called cracker apple pie the crust is made of crackers

Comment: Can you show us the recipe? I suspect any acid in the right amount will work for an actual apple pie. Is it *mock* apple pie, made with Ritz crackers, and no apples? If so, that calls for a LOT of cream of tartar, plus another acid (lemon juice). In that case, I would be nervous about any substitution. Certainly, don't try to substitute baking powder. That will throw the chemistry right off.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Totally agree. Follow up is needed from the OP for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Baking powder cannot be used as a substitute for cream of tartar.

Cream of tartar is used in recipes as a dry acid.

Baking powder has cream of tartar added to leavening agents that have a basic pH. Thus baking powder as a whole is not acidic.